# File not found inside "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am accessing a file from 
"`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/1565704523555.jpg`". When I check if the file exists it tells me that the file was not found.
I have given all run-time permissions.

When I list all files from "`/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/`" I can see the file in that directory.

Whenever I use "`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+/Pictures`"
I can access all the files from this folders and it shows that the file exists.

I am trying this on an emulator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+/Pictures`.

And if you want to use your private application pictures directory use `context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)`, where `context` is Android `Context`

Comment: Thanks. Its Working Now.